# npm commands not working with vscode terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode terminal in order to run my npm commands. After I run the npm command it will generate the following error. here is an example for that.

```
PS C:\Users\Chandra Prakash\Desktop\Node.jeWork\Bakend> npx express-generator
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Chandra'
command not found: express-generator
```

Comment: Seems like you haven't installed the express-genratore make sure to install it globally. `npm install express -g`

Answer (score 3):

Username with spaces may be resulting in this error

Try create a link to your user folder:

Step 1

```
cmd /c mklink /J "C:\Users\chandraprakash" "C:\Users\Chandra Prakash"
```

Step 2

```
npm config set cache C:\Users\chandraprakash\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

Step 3

```
npm config set prefix C:\Users\chandraprakash\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

This should solve.

Clear the cache if it still doesn't work:

```
npm cache clean --force
```